# What does だらっと mean?

Tags: meaning, adverbs, japanese-to-english

As far as I know it should mean slow. But I haven't found this word on any online or offline dictionary.

> たとえばゆるい幸せがだらっと続いたとする

So the word is used in the song Solanin by Asian Kung-Fu Generation. The first time I heard this word was in the 1st episode of the anime **"The Daily Life of High-school Boys"**. It was subtitled as slow. However, since then I haven't found it on any dictionary; I looked up online but still in vain. Does this word really exist and if it does, what does it really mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「だらっ」 is defined in several sources.

As per [プログレッシブ和英中辞典(第３版)](https://kotobank.jp/jeword/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%89%E3%81%A3):

> 1 〔粘っこい液体が垂れる様子〕
> 赤ん坊はだらっとよだれを垂らしていた
> The baby was drooling [slobbering].
>
> 2 〔だらしない様子〕
> だらっとする
> ⇒だらける
> だらっとしてないで勉強しなさい
> Stop loafing [fooling about] and start studying.

Similarly, [this page](http://sura-sura.com/archives/3372.html) has:

> 力なく、または、だらしなくたれ下がるさま。
> 液体が不快な感じで、したたるさま。

「だらっ」 is etymologically and semantically related to [だらだら](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%A0%E3%82%89%E3%81%A0%E3%82%89)

> 3. sluggishly; endlessly; lengthily​
>    Onomatopoeic or mimetic word
> 4. leisurely; idly; slowly; slovenly​
>    Onomatopoeic or mimetic word
>    話は三時までだらだらと続いた。
>    The talk dragged on till three o'clock.

In your sentence, it means something along the lines of slowly, sluggishly, endlessly.